# Custom Order By, How do I let User to select fields on which to Order A List<T>

Tags: c#, list, lambda

I have a `List<T>` and now i have to show a page to user on which every of the fields inside  object are shown with a checkbox.

Now if user checks any of them, or check all of them, or lets say select's none of them, how do I order my list accordingly?

There are some 8 fields out of which user can select any combination, so the data inside the list should be accordingly ordered.

I am currently using `List<>` method `OrderBy()`.

Any help would be appreciated.

here is How i am using the method but in my case there are 8 fields now how many combinations can becomes of them I cannot put so many ifs there.

SortedList = list.OrderBy(x => x.QuantityDelivered).ThenBy(x => x.Quantity).ToList();

Comment: Please share what have you tried. It would be easier to help if you've shown your code.

Comment: Just FYI, `OrderBy` is an extension method for `IEnumerable<T>` and isn't directly part of `List<T>`. I would personally do this using a custom `IComparer<T>` definition that you can then provide in conjunction with calling `Sort` on the list. The implementation of the `IComparer<T>` interface can then take into account the fields that are selected by the user.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby-on-ienumerablet

Comment: I have added the code that i am trying right now.

Comment: well +Sriram Sakthivel, I m sorry! the Answer to that Question is just over my head i don't quite Understand that and I am not that Experienced in c# so perhap's some simple solution If Possible from the Expert guys out there. though thank you already.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are able to determine in your code which field was clicked for sorting:

```
IEnumerable<T> items = // code to get initial data, 
                       // set to be an IEnumerable. with default sort applied
List<string> sortFields = // code to get the sort fields into a list,
                          // in order of selection
bool isFirst = true;

foreach (string sortField in sortFields) {
  switch (sortField )
  {
      case "field1":
          if (isFirst) {
            items = items.OrderBy(x => x.Field1);
          } else {
            items = items.ThenBy(x => x.Field1);
          }
          break;
      case "field2":
          if (isFirst) {
            items = items.OrderBy(x => x.Field2);
          } else {
            items = items.ThenBy(x => x.Field2);
          }
          break;
      // perform for all fields
  }
  isFirst = false
}

var listOfItems = items.ToList();
```

The list is now sorted by the selected field, usable in whatever way you see fit.

Might be safer to convert the sort fields to an enum, and `switch` on that to avoid errors with copying strings.

Comment: is it hard to pass lambda itself and then call `items.OrderBy(selector)`? And not to rely on string reflection?

Comment: I have 8 fields out of which the user may selects the first and last fields or may be you can just go on and on.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth and khalid: I switched the logic to handle multiple selected fields